# Toast gravity produces incorrect vertical position

Tags: android, toast

When I do this:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
```

...the top edge of the toast is about 24 pixels from the top of the screen.  The toast's background happens to be about 48 pixels high.  Coincidence?  What's going on here?

(The top of the screen is not really where I want it.  I only put it there to try to figure why the vertical position is wrong.)

Comment: `Gravity` with a `Toast` is a general statement of where you want it. It is not an absolute position.

Comment: @CommonsWare What's the point of an API allowing a precise offset from a general position?

Comment: Ummm... good question. I forgot that those other two parameters were X and Y offsets. My apologies. The `Toast` source code shows that those values wind up going into the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` that is used for the `Toast` window.

Comment: Is the 24 pixels your top margin for the layout?

Comment: @CommonsWare FYI, I posted an answer.  Not sure if I found a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure that qualifies as a bug, but it would seem to be an explanation. My guess is that if you filed an actual bug report, if you got any response, it would be "working as intended".

Answer (score 1):

I found an explanation, though not a solution.  It appears that the toast position does not take into account that the navigation and status bars are hidden in full screen mode, and positions itself as if they were visible.

My activity sets full screen mode in `onCreate` and `onWindowFocusChanged`.  I tried displaying the toast as late as possible, by posting it to a handler from `onPostResume`, but it still behaves as if the system UI were visible.

In case I'm missing something, this is how I'm setting full screen mode:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void enableFullScreenMode() {
    int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

    /* Calling setSystemUiVisibility directly works most of the time, but
     * sometimes the navigation bar gets stuck, covering part of the UI.
     * Posting it seems to prevent this. */
    final int finalFlags = flags;
    getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(finalFlags);
        }
    });
}
```